# saving file while receiving file in upload to server

Tags: php

I am gonna to save file when the file is still uploading to the server!

For example, the client uploads a video to the server and I want to get that file and save it when client waits to finish it. in other words, I want to save uploaded file every 100kb.

Maybe you ask me, why I am going to do this! Here is why:

I am creating a video conferencing stream by PHP, I want to save uploading video and get it in another clients device!

Can I use `php://` to get that file?

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

Comment: You may be able to use chunked uploading from the client to upload a large file in parts, but for video-conferencing, don't you need to start the upload while the video is still being created? Maybe an open socket connection would be better suited for this.

Comment: @rickdenhaan clients hardwares have not enough resource and hardware to chunk videos!

Comment: It's not about chunking the videos, it's about uploading them in chunks. All the client has to do is read and upload a certain number of bytes from the file from a given offset, instead of reading and uploading the entire file. That doesn't take any specific hardware requirements.